# touch event for whole android application

Tags: android

I am developing a new app in which i had a great doubt whether is it possible or not?
My doubt is

We have to set one time listener for whole application. And we have to run a set of code for any touch event occurs in our application. **For eg.** there may be n activities in our app. But we have to set one time listener for all activities and run a set code when any touch occurs in any of n activities. I have tried a lot for it. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "receive broadcast"? receive to where?

Comment: changed my question, can you understand now?

Answer (score 3):

I hope I understand you right.

What that you can do is create a class that extends Activity, Lets say TouchActivity.
each one of your activities will inherit TouchActivity.

```
 public class TouchActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            Log.d("Touch", "Touch");
            sendBroadcast(new Intent("touch_event_has_occured"));
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

now in your global broadcast receiver you will get the brodcast

```
public class TouchReveiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("touch_event_has_occured"))
        {
            Log.d("Touch", "Touch");
        }
    }

}
```

don't forget to register the receiver with the action

Comment: How to register receiver with this action? I do this like below :  ```  <receiver android:name=".TouchReveiver">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.touch_event_has_occured" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom view that's invisible, takes all the screen and uses onTouchEvent to perform whatever operation you need to do.

Then you'll need to have every layout file to include that view on top (probably in a FrameLayout).

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is, create a base activity class that is extended by all other activities in your application. You can then override the `public boolean dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)` method in this base activity. This overridden implementation would be the single place where all your touch events land.

There is one important caveat though, it will work only in case all your activities are of the  same type (for example - all of them are `Activitiy` types or all of them are of type `ListActivity`)

Comment: Your answer was the only one who worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Totally Possible.

Create a Activity called `MyTouchActivity` (or something) override the `onTouch` Event and write the `set` code you're talking about.

And now, all the rest of the `n` Activities should extend `MyTouchActivity` instead of the Regular Activity. This way that code is inherited to all your n Activities. You'll need to create Seperate `MyTouchListActivity` (for ListActivity) and MyTouchMapActivity (for MapActivity)

The other Method would be to simply create an Ontouch LIstener and then override each `onTocuh` event in each activity to call your Listener first. But that's cumbersome.

Comment: its working, but if i add a button in any of activity and if i click the button means, the ontouch event is not working!

Comment: @Srinivas, Sorry could you be more specific? Are the buttons not rsponding to clicks? Did you register onClickListeners? In the `onTouch`, did you return false? If you return true, the touch event is not passed down to the components (eg, buttons etc) make sure you return false or `super.onTouch()`.

Comment: when i print a log in ontouchevent(), it prints that log when it touches empty screen, but it does not print when i click a button on that same screen.

Comment: @Srinivas, aah, I suppose the opposite happens, the touch event is first given to the components and then to the activity. Now the Button has a Touch overided, so when you click on it, it doesn't not bubble up that event to the activity. I think you'll have to make a Global OnTouchListener and set it for each component you want to intercept.

Answer (score 0):

If you whant to use this for whole app you need to create class that extends from ActionBarActivity(or SherlockActivity)

```
public class MyCustomActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FrameLayout decorView = (FrameLayout) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Click X:" + event.getX() + " Y:" + event.getY());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and then extends all other Activities from MyCustomActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends MyCustomActivity{ }
```

Than all touch events will go through your TouchListener event

Answer (score 0):

The solutions that use the `dispatchTouchEvent` or `onTouch` methods don't work for the entire application. Because there are different types of windows. For example, these solutions will not be able to catch touch events if a fragment pops-up or the user clicks a menu because in those cases other things are going on.

Long story short, I was dealing with this problem for my senior project and I developed a library that is able to collect all touch events for an application. The library depends on tricky ways but it also works. The library is open source. You may examine it if you want: https://github.com/fatih-iver/touchy

Just add it as a dependency:

```
implementation 'fun.observe:touchy:1.0.0'
```

Then, use it by registering your receiver:

```
MotionEventBroadcaster.registerReceiver(new MotionEventReceiver() {
    @Override
    protected void onReceive(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d(TAG, motionEvent.toString());
    }
});
```